# How to add samlResponse parameter to thinktecture response

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, thinktecture-ident-server

I am trying to use Thinktecture Identity server v2 with a 3rd party web application which expect SAMLResponse and RelayState as  parameters. When i checked the idp response in fiddler all i see is "wresult" as parameter with the token as value and another "wa" param. Is it possible to get SAMLResponse as response parameter from thinktecture idp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAMLResponse is part of SAML2P response message. Thinktecture IdentityServer does not have this protocol implemented. Please see [this issue](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/pull/139).

If using SAML2P is your hard requirement then I would suggest to try different IAM like  [Shiboleth](https://shibboleth.net/products/identity-provider.html) or try to implement the feature to IdentityServer yourself. There are .net libraries out there that implement SAML2P. You could look at [OIOSAML.NET](http://digitaliser.dk/group/42063/resources) or [ComponentPro UltimateSAML](http://www.componentpro.com/saml.net/)

Comment: FWIW, please see cheated.by.safabyte.net which shows Component Pro likely represents the latest incarnation of stolen SAML software. TY